# The gulp plugin creation is not working

Tags: ionic-framework, gulp, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm trying to write an Ionic-Native Plugin and as i found even on the ionic forum, they're using gulp plugin:create but when i try any command this error comes out:

> no gulpfile found

Any idea what should i do?

To add gulp I installed gulp:

> npm install -g gulp

Comment: well you are missing a `gulpfile.js`

Comment: I have to just add it manually and then create myself the plugin:create?